# Time interval between clicks on the same button - shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry for asking dummy question. I am quite sure that it has an easy solution but I still could not figure it out.

I have an action button, I click on it several times and I should have the time interval between the clicks.

**Example,**

I click on the button now, and again two minutes later, again 4 minutes after the second click, and again 5 minutes after the third click and so on.

2 minutes = Time difference between the second click and the first click

4 minutes = Time difference between the third click and the second click

5 minutes = Time difference between the fourth click and the third click

I could do it with two buttons which is easy but with one button I have no idea how it would be.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried with one button so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a closure. Closures allow functions to maintain their state between invocations.

Each time `timer()` is run, it creates a new environment and initialises the time in that environment. Then it creates a new function that maintains access to the environment in which it was created. By then using the `<<-` operator to modify the `x` variable one level up, you can store the time every time the function is called.

```r
library(shiny)

timer <- function(){
  x <- Sys.time()
  y <- function(){
    y <- x
    x <<- Sys.time()
    return(x-y)
  }
  return(y)
}

# Implement a simple shiny app with an action button that
# prints the result of running click()
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # click is defined within the server function so each
  # session has their own click function with a stored
  # time.
  click <- timer()
  observeEvent(input$do, {print(click())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For more information on this technique, you can read Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R: Functional Programming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functional-programming.html)

EDIT: If you want to ignore the first click / return something else on the first click, you can do something like:

```r
library(shiny)

timer <- function(){
  x <- NULL
  y <- function(){
    y <- x
    x <<- Sys.time()
    if(is.null(y))
      return("first click")
    return(x-y)
  }
  return(y)
}

# Implement a simple shiny app with an action button that
# prints the result of running click()
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # click is defined within the server function so each
  # session has their own click function with a stored
  # time.
  click <- timer()
  observeEvent(input$do, {print(click())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Like a Piece of cake.

Comment: This is a nice solution. However, one drawback of this technique is that it won't work if you host your app on a server (or locally), and multiple users share a process - try opening two sessions at once by copy-pasting the URL in your browser. If user 1 clicks and then user 2 clicks, you will get the time interval between user 2's last click and user1's last click, instead of the interval between subsequent clicks of one user. This is because the `<<-` operator pushes the value to the global environment, which is shared by all users in a process.

Comment: @Florian you are right, of course. I have edited my answer to what I should have put originally. The benefit of using the `<<-` operator  is that it stores the value in the environment of the `click()` function rather than the global environment. Putting the definition of `click()` inside the `server` function means that the value should be 'per session'.

Comment: @Eumenedies, I had not thought of that, that is indeed a simple and clean solution to that issue.

Comment: @Eumenedies, How I should ignore the first click in your solution? since I should not get an answer when I click for the first time.

Comment: @EsterSilva instead of initialising `x <- Sys.time()`, initialise `x <- NULL`. Then you can check the value of `y` before returning the difference using `is.null(y)` (after `y <- x`) to check whether the button has been clicked before. You will want to make sure that `x <<- Sys.time()` is called regardless of the value of `y` or `x` since that is what stores the most recent click.

Comment: @Eumenedies, Please correct me if I understood you wrong, You mean something like:  
if (!is.null(y))
{  x <<- Sys.time()
    return(x-y)
}

Comment: @EsterSilva please see my edited response. You need to put `x <<- Sys.time()` outside the conditional otherwise it will never evaluate and the value of `x` will not change when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks much @Eumenedies.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example. You can store all the click times in an `reactiveVal`, update this vector with an `observeEvent` any time the `actionButton` is clicked, and use `diff` on this vector to calculate the time intervals in seconds. Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
ui <-   fluidPage(
  actionButton('mybutton','press me'),
  textOutput('mytext'),
  textOutput('mytext2')
)

server <- function(input,output)
{
  click_times <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$mybutton, {
    click_times(c(click_times(),Sys.time()))
  })

  # print all intervals in seconds
  output$mytext <- renderText({
    if(length(click_times())<2)
    {'Less than two clicks!'} else {
      paste0('Time intervals: ', paste(round(diff(click_times()),2),collapse=' seconds, '),' seconds.')}
  })

  # print last interval in minutes:seconds format
  output$mytext2 <- renderText({
    if(length(click_times())<2)
    {'Less than two clicks!'} else {
      ct <- as.POSIXct(round(tail(diff(click_times()),1),2), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
      paste0('Last interval: ' ,format(ct,'%M:%S')) }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Just for curiosity @Florian. How your solution would be for minutes instead of seconds? since you use diff function.

Comment: You could divide the number by 60 to get the seconds, and do `number %% 60` to get the minutes. Alternatively you can convert to `POSIXct` and format from there, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the package `library(tictoc)`. With a `reactiveVal` and using the button itself as a counter.

```
library(shiny); library(tictoc)
ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("timer", "click me"), textOutput("text"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  time = reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$timer, handlerExpr = {
    time(capture.output(toc()))
    tic()})
  output$text = renderText({ifelse(is.null(time()), "start!", paste0(time(), " : Time difference between click No", input$timer, " and click No", max(0, input$timer - 1)))})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```